# Java 8 Nashorn whitespace issue

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn

UPDATE:

I have a gross solution that works, but I don't like it:

jjs> NANO_HOME = '"/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST DIR"';
jjs> $EXEC('xargs ls',"${NANO_HOME}");

---

I am using Java 8 Nashorn to do some shell scripting, and I'm having issues with listing files in a directory if the directory name contains a space:

```
$ jjs -scripting
jjs> `ls /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/`
TEST DIR
jjs> `ls /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST DIR`

jjs> $ERR
ls: /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST: No such file or directory
ls: DIR: No such file or directory  

jjs> `ls "/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST DIR"`

jjs> $ERR
ls: "/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST: No such file or directory
ls: DIR": No such file or directory

jjs> `ls /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST\u0020DIR`

jjs> $ERR
ls: /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST: No such file or directory
ls: DIR: No such file or directory

jjs> `ls /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST\ DIR`

jjs> $ERR
ls: /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/TEST: No such file or directory
ls: DIR: No such file or directory
```

I've tried dozens of variations and nothing works...

Comment: Have you tried quotes around the whole string? Double-escaped whitespace (`\\ `)?

Comment: yes I have, unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Note: the backquotes really have to be there; that's the way `jjs` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like the backquote syntax for invoking system commands (as well as the `$EXEC` function, which does the same thing) mishandles arguments that contain whitespace.

The source code is in the `exec` function in [ScriptingFunctions.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/nashorn/file/jdk8-b132/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/ScriptingFunctions.java) file. Unfortunately it uses a plain `StringTokenizer` to split the string into an array of argument strings, which are then passed to `ProcessBuilder`. This means that whitespace, quoting, backslashes, and so forth, are not taken into account.

I'd say this is a bug. There should be a way to pass an argument array directly to `$EXEC` instead of having it parse the string into arguments, but I'm not aware of one.

**UPDATE**

Enhancement request [JDK-8049300](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8049300) filed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ls \"/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/TEST DIR\"
```

Does that work for you? (It does on Windows if you enclose the line in back ticks).